# Extension of prime ideals to completion are irreducible ideals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $(R,\frak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring. I am trying to prove that if the natural map $\operatorname{Spec}(\widehat R)\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is bijective then $\mathfrak{p}\widehat R $ is irreducible for all $\mathfrak p\in \operatorname{Spec}(R)$.

Thank you for your proof or comment.

Comment: What's an example of such an $R$?

Comment: A DVR (or any local domain of dimension 1 whose completion is still a domain) would be an example. I can't think of anything in higher dimension though.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Hailong Dao!